# Putting values in a linked list ( c programming)

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to put values in a linked list.

First, I created a `document.h` called `linkedlist.h` in which I put all functions used for a linked list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct lc{
 int valeur;
 struct lc * suivant;
}lc;



void Add(lc * debut,int element){      
   lc *b;                              
   b=(lc*)malloc(sizeof(lc));
   b->valeur=element;                  
   b->suivant=debut;                   
   debut=b;                         
 }
 
 void Show(lc *liste)
 {         
    lc *cour;                              
    cour=liste;                           
       if (liste==NULL)
         printf("the list is empty");
       else
           {
              while(cour !=NULL)
                {
                  printf("%d",cour->valeur);
                  cour=cour->suivant;
                }
           }    
  }
```

in my function main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lc.h"

void main()
{
    lc *MaListe; /*un pointeur sur une liste chainee */
    MaListe=NULL;
    int element=5;
    Add(MaListe,element);
    Show(MaListe);
}
```

I can execute my program but I get that the liste is empty.

Comment: In `Add`, the list head `debut` is a local variable. Changing it will not affect `MaListe` in `main`.

Comment: So I think that the function Add is not a void type but must return the pointer of our new linked list ?

Comment: Yes, that's one possibility. But see my answer for (in my opinion) a better one.

Answer (score 0):

In `Add`, when you update the list head:

```
debut = b;
```

you change a local variable. This change will not be seen in `main` and it will not change the value of `MaListe`.

There are basically two ways to solve this. The first is to return the new head:

```
lc *Add(lc *debut, int element)
{
    lc *b = malloc(sizeof(lc));
    b->valeur = element;
    b->suivant = *debut;

    return b;
}
```

and the call:

```
MaListe = Add(MaListe, element);
```

This is a bit redundant and potentially dangerous, because you can omit (or "forget") the assignment. In C, you can pass a pointer to the head pointer and update `MaListe` through tat pointer:

```
void Add(lc **debut, int element)
{
    lc *b;

    b = (lc *) malloc(sizeof(lc));
    b->valeur = element;
    b->suivant = *debut;
    *debut = b;                  // Modifies what debut points to,
                                 // namely MaListe in main
}
```

Call this function by creating a pointer to the node pointer with the address operator `&`:

```
Add(&MaListe, element);
```

I prefer this variant, because the `&` makes it explicit that the head pointer may change. Also, there's only one occurrence of `MaListe` here.

Answer (score 0):

last answer's correction :

'

```
lc *Add(lc* debut, int element) {
    lc* b = malloc(sizeof(lc));
    b->valeur = element;
    b->suivant = debut;

    return b;
```

}

'